# Error - Problema con una función JS al hacer un CRUD

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, crud

Estoy haciendo una lectura de un formulario situado en una ventana modal con una función JS. En ese formulario hay varios datos "normales" y un archivo(imagen). Tras varias comprobaciones, hago la subida del archivo mediante un archivo php al servidor. Una vez echa la subida, paso el nombre del archivo junto a los demás datos del formulario y hago un INSERT típico mediante ajax. Dejo el código del JS:

```
$("#btnAddProductoModal").on('click', function () {

    let file_data = $('#imagenModal').prop('files')[0];
    let form = $("#formAddProducto");
    let check = checkCampos(form);
    var imagen = "";

    if (check) {

        if (file_data != undefined) {

            let form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);

            if (file_data['name'] != $('#addImagenHidden').val()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/insertar_imagen.php",
                    data: form_data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (resp) {
                        imagen = resp;
                        addProducto(imagen);            
                    }
                });
            } else {
                imagen = $('#addImagenHidden').val();
                addProducto(imagen);
            }
        } else {
            imagen = $('#addImagenHidden').val();
            addProducto(imagen);
        }
    alert("Alta de producto correcta"); 
    }       
});
```

Y este sería el PHP de la subida del archivo:

```
<?php
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$url_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/crmkrc/images';

if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
    echo false;
} else {
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$url_dir/$name")){
        $imagen = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo $imagen; 
    } else{
        echo false;
    }
}
?>
```

y finalmente la función addProducto es la que hace el INSERT

```
    function addProducto(imagen) {
    datos = {
        'imagen': imagen,
        'nombre': $("#nombreProductoModal").val(),
        'descripcion': $("#descripcionModal").val(),
        'ficha': $("#fichaModal").val(),
        'limite': $("#limiteModal").val(),
        'categoria': $("#categoriaModal").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/insertarProducto.php",
        data: datos,
        success: function (resp) {
            $('#modalAddProducto').modal('hide');
            $("#mensajeadminprendas").show();
            $("#mensajeadminprendas").html(resp);
            setTimeout( function(){
                    window.location.replace("prendas.php");
            },2500);    
        }
    }); 
};
```

El problema es que si quito el ALERT que hay al final de la primera función, no se realiza la inserción. Incluso si lo cambio por un ELSE para cerrar el IF o un console.log no funciona. Sabríais decirme que ocurre?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: A mi me suena que si esta haciendo la insercion, el alert no tiene ninguna relevancia ahi, quizas deberias agregar la propiedad error en los ajax para ver si esta muriendo a la hora de hacer el request y ver que te esta devolviendo

Comment: Si la eliminación de la función alert() no está provocando que se realice el INSERT, es posible que haya algún error en la función addProducto(). Podrías intentar agregar una línea console.log(datos) justo antes de la llamada a $.ajax() dentro de la función addProducto() para verificar que los datos que se están enviando al archivo PHP sean correctos. Si los datos no son correctos, podría ser el causante del problema. Otro posible problema es que la función addProducto() no se esté ejecutando correctamente. Podrías añadir una línea console.log('addProducto()') al comienzo de la función addProd

Comment: Según estuve leyendo es porque el alert "retrasa" la ejecución y da tiempo a que el se realice el INSERT y dé tiempo a devolver el success al Ajax. En resumen, si no ha alert, el Ajax se ejecuta y es mas rápido en terminar que el INSERT y por tanto no se realizaría.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda prestada.